# Deep link into a power app that is already open

Tags: powerapps

I have managed to get deep linking into a diary entry in my app from an email to work fine when the app is not loaded

If I have 2 emails, one pointing to diary entry id 45 and the other pointing to 47, how do I get both to work?

If the app is closed and I click on the link for entry 45 it works fine

Now I go to the link for 47

This doesn't work, the app loads but nothing happens

I have this in my app startup

If(IsBlank(Param("diaryEntryId")),'Main Screen', 'Single Diary Entry')
In the OnVisible of my Single Diary Entry screen I have this

If(
IsBlank(Param("diaryEntryId")) = false,
UpdateContext({diaryEntryIdFromParams: Value(Param("diaryEntryId"))}),
UpdateContext({diaryEntryIdFromParams: 0})
);
If(
diaryEntryId > 0,
Set(
varSingleDiaryEntry,
LookUp(
'Site Diary Entries',
ID = diaryEntryId
)
);
Set(
varInternalId,
varSingleDiaryEntry.InternalID
);
,
If(
diaryEntryIdFromParams = 0,
Set(
varInternalId,
Text(GUID())
);
Set(
varSingleDiaryEntry,
Patch(
Defaults('Site Diary Entries'),
{InternalID: varInternalId}
)
);
,
Set(
varSingleDiaryEntry,
LookUp(
'Site Diary Entries',
ID = diaryEntryIdFromParams
)
);
Set(
varInternalId,
varSingleDiaryEntry.InternalID
);
);
);

How can I get around this?

Paul